# Which JDBC driver type should I use for accessing an Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jakarta-ee

We're running a J2EE Application inside a Tomcat WebServer on AIX.

We need to access a few Views and Stored Procedures of an Oracle Database. This oracle datebase is not the one our application is based on, but an external system we have to communicate with.

As far as I can tell from now, we are going to get around a 1000 SELECTs per minute on high load and a few stored procedure calls per hour, if any.

Which JDBC driver type would be the best to use in this situation?

As far as I have gathered type 4 seems to be the way to go, but I haven't been able to find a definite statement about this by Oracle or some other reliable source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Type 4 ("thin") driver is the recommended driver by Oracle.

The only reason to use the OCI ("thick") driver is when you need the advanced features of a RAC such as transparent application failover (TAF). For everything else the thin driver is recommended.

See the JDBC Developer's Guide for details:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/overvw.htm#BABCHIGI

The most important sentence is probably:

> *In general, unless you need OCI-specific features, such as support for non-TCP/IP networks, use the JDBC Thin driver.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you maybe post a link or send me in the right direction for that recommendetion by Oracle? Because to be honest, I already would have settled on Type 4, if it wasn't for my client being sceptical so I need something to show for.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience I'd suggest using Thin driver. However there are 3 situations in which I'd advice OCI:

1. DB and JVM running your program is on the same host. In such case OCI will omit TCP/IP layer and communication might be faster
2. You need only Oracle SID to connect to DB, since full client is used. You don't need full DB URL. This might be useful in configuration in dev/test/prod environment.
3. You are calling Stored Procedures very (I mean it!) frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Type 4 seems to be the way to go but you can decide yourself by going through the pros/cons [listed here.](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-driver-types.htm)